In a graded algebra $B$, is $B_+$ always prime?
I'm sure that this question is very easy but I couldn't really find an answer on the internet.
Let $B$ be a graded $A$-algebra.
We have $B=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$, and we have the ideal $B_+:=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb N^+}B_n$, which is clearly homogeneous.
Is $B_+$ a prime ideal?
I would say yes: $B_+$ is homogeneous so we can check that, if $x,y\in B$ are homogeneous and $xy\in B_+$ (i.e. $\operatorname{deg} xy\gt 0$), either $x\in B_+$ or $y\in B_+$ (since either $\operatorname{deg} x\gt 0$ or $\operatorname{deg} y\gt 0$).
However this would mean that $B_0$ is always an integral domain for any graded  algebra, and I doubt that this is true so in general. What do you think? Thanks in advance.

Since neither of the (correct) answers mentioned it, I'll just leave this as a comment: $B/B_+ \simeq B_0$, so $B_+$ is a prime ideal if and only if $B_0$ is an integral domain.

Note that any $A$-algebra $B$ is also a ($\mathbb{N}$-)graded algebra in a natural way: take $B_0=B$ and $B_n = 0$ for all $n \neq 0$. What you are asking is equivalent to that every $A$-algebra is integral, but that is clearly false: just take $B_0=B=A[x]/(x^2)$.

You're right, could the reason be that the axioms of an $A$-algebra $B$ say that $B_nB_m\subset B_{mn}$ and not $\operatorname{deg}xy=\operatorname{deg}x+\operatorname{deg}y$?

@EzioGreggio yea that is satisfied

Your proof that $B_+$ is prime is convincing at first glance, but there's a subtlety: Note that if $B_+$ is to be an ideal then it must include $0$, but if it includes zero and $B_0$ is not a domain you can find $a, b \in B_0 \setminus \{0\}$ with $ab = 0 \in B_+$, so $B_+$ is not prime.
One generally should be a bit careful around 0 when reasoning in graded algebras, since reasoning by degree can fail there (what should the degree of 0 even be?).

$0$ can be considered of degree $-\infty$ :)

...and then require that $B_m B_n \subseteq B_{m + n} \cup B_{-\infty}$? :)

nope. that does not mean $0 \notin B_n$ - in fact, each $B_n$ has to contain $0$ since they are abelian groups ($A$-modules) in their own right.

@SalutaFungo ...yes, and if you put these together and think about what relation you may want between some element being in $B_n$ and its degree then you'll understand why I asked that rhetorical question :)

welp, that is precisely how the notion of degree behave poorly. I'd say $B_mB_n \subseteq B_{m+n}$ suffice and just leave degrees aside :o
